# Spine SkletonData won't take material in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, spine, materials

I've used assets in Unity made with [Spine](https://ko.esotericsoftware.com/).

GameObjects I create from SkeletonData files will look like this:
[image: missing material]

At first glance the problem seems obvious; In the Mesh renderer, it says the material is missing. However, adding my material won't work here and it says:

```
Problematic Texture / Material Settings found: It is recommended to disable `Alpha Is Transparency` on `Premultiply alpha` textures.
```

Firstly, it doesn't sound like a good idea to disable this in the first place, because alpha channels should be transparency, right? Also I did some digging and found [this query](https://ko.esotericsoftware.com/forum/d/15521-problematic-material-setup-at-spine-animation-but-its-not/2) on the Spine forums. In this thread, the user says what worked for them was:
deleting the line

```
_ALPHAPREMULTIPLY_ON
```

in their material file. Despite the user uttering concern about this solution, my file doesn't even have that line to delete. This is the code of my material file:

```
%YAML 1.1
%TAG !u! tag:unity3d.com,2011:
--- !u!21 &2100000
Material:
  serializedVersion: 8
  m_ObjectHideFlags: 0
  m_CorrespondingSourceObject: {fileID: 0}
  m_PrefabInstance: {fileID: 0}
  m_PrefabAsset: {fileID: 0}
  m_Name: spineboy-pro_Material
  m_Shader: {fileID: 4800000, guid: 1e8a610c9e01c3648bac42585e5fc676, type: 3}
  m_ValidKeywords: []
  m_InvalidKeywords:
  - _USE8NEIGHBOURHOOD_ON
  m_LightmapFlags: 4
  m_EnableInstancingVariants: 0
  m_DoubleSidedGI: 0
  m_CustomRenderQueue: -1
  stringTagMap: {}
  disabledShaderPasses: []
  m_SavedProperties:
    serializedVersion: 3
    m_TexEnvs:
    - _MainTex:
        m_Texture: {fileID: 2800000, guid: 581a7e3dd3386284391da5fa454a3ddd, type: 3}
        m_Scale: {x: 1, y: 1}
        m_Offset: {x: 0, y: 0}
    m_Ints: []
    m_Floats:
    - _Cutoff: 0.1
    - _OutlineMipLevel: 0
    - _OutlineOpaqueAlpha: 1
    - _OutlineReferenceTexWidth: 1024
    - _OutlineSmoothness: 1
    - _OutlineWidth: 3
    - _StencilComp: 8
    - _StencilRef: 1
    - _StraightAlphaInput: 0
    - _ThresholdEnd: 0.25
    - _Use8Neighbourhood: 1
    m_Colors:
    - _OutlineColor: {r: 1, g: 1, b: 0, a: 1}
  m_BuildTextureStacks: []
```

I've tried three different Spine projects, they all have the same problem. Even the Spine Examples included in the Spine package will look like this. Weirdly enough, I can assign these materials to Vanilla Unity GamebeObjects tho.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I am having the same issues.